# Remove Only One Duplicate from An Array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to only remove one of the 2s from an array, but my code removes all of them. My code is as follows:

```
var arr = [2,7,9,5,2]
arr.filter(item => ((item !== 2)));
```

and:

```
var arr = [2,7,9,2,2,5,2]
arr.filter(item => ((item !== 2)));
```

Both remove all the 2s. I thought about removing duplicates, where it works if there's only one duplicate - e.g.:

```
Array.from(new Set([2,7,9,5,2]));
function uniq(a) {
 return Array.from(new Set(a)) 
}
```

But fails if there's multiple duplicates as it just removes them all, including any other duplicated numbers:

```
Array.from(new Set([2,7,9,9,2,2,5,2]));
function uniq(a) {
 return Array.from(new Set(a)) 
}
```

Does anyone know how to only remove one of the 2s? Thanks for any help here.

Comment: create a simple loop, when found an index with value of 2: `.splice(idx, 1)` this index and `break` the loop

Comment: Which one do you want to remove ?  The first `2`, or last, or ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `indexOf` method in combination with `splice`.

```js
var arr = [2,7,9,5,2]
var idx = arr.indexOf(2)
if (idx >= 0) {
    arr.splice(idx, 1);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Close, but it won't work correctly if the number isn't present on the array; checking if `indexOf` is non-negative would make it more robust.

Answer (score 4):

You could take a closure with a counter and remove only the first `2`.

```js
var array = [2, 7, 9, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2],
    result = array.filter((i => v => v !== 2 || --i)(1));
    
console.log(result);
```

For any other `2`, you could adjust the start value for decrementing.

```js
var array = [2, 7, 9, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2],
    result = array.filter((i => v => v !== 2 || --i)(2));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: interesting answer. What does the v and (1) and (2) represent? I'm new to JS and haven't seen this type of syntax before - can you link to anything I can read to learn this?

Comment: one is to remove the first occurence of `2` and two for the second, and so on. it works, because the number gets decremented and if zero, the value is filterd out. the technique's name is closure with an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression).

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do that; one relatively simple way would be to use `indexOf`; see this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357/679240

```js
var array = [2, 7, 9, 5, 2];
console.log(array)
var index = array.indexOf(2);
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
// array = [7, 9, 5, 2]
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const arr = [2, 7, 9, 2, 2, 5, 2];
const result = arr
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    a.temp[c] = ++a.temp[c] || 1;
    if (a.temp[c] !== 2) {
      a.array.push(c);
    }
    return a;
  }, {temp: {}, array: []})
  .array;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the following method

```
var arr= [2,3,4,2,4,5];
var unique = [];
$.each(arr, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, unique) === -1) unique.push(el);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way to filter all duplicates from array:

```
arr.filter((item, position) => arr.indexOf(item) === position)
```

This method skip element if another element with the same value already exist.

If you need to filter only first duplicate, you can use additional bool key:

```
arr.filter((item, position) => {
  if (!already && arr.indexOf(item) !== position) {
    already = true
    return false
  } else return true
})
```

But this method have overheaded. Smartest way is use `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr.indexOf(arr[i]) !== i) {
    arr.splice(i,1);
    break;
  }
}
```